La he liado muy parda con NuGet en .NET MAUI blazor y no se que hacer
Ayer empecé con .NET MAUI Blazor, no tenía, ni tengo, ni idea pero me ilusionaba el potencial que tiene. El caso que tuve problemas porque el botón de "Administrar paquetes NuGet..." estaba deshabilitado, luego he caído en que era por que estaba debugeando... El caso que desinstalé la extensión y luego tiré a instalarla pero perdí todo el formato visual del típico código de ejemplo con el home, contador y weather.
Instalé varios paquetes NuGets e incluso hice una reparación del instalador pero nada. Finalmente desinstalé visual studio 2022 y lo volví a instalar pero nada... Creo que en este punto, para un servidor inexperto, sería reinstalar el SO (Windows 10) y perder otro día de trabajo, pero este ordenador es de empresa y no me sería tan fácil.
Gracias! Pablo.
Pd. Pongo capturas de cómo está la plantilla o el ejemplo sin modificar nada, obviamente he probado en otros emuladores y dispositivos físicos:


Al final probando todo lo posible se ha solucionado, por un lado he vuelto a desinstalar visual studio 2022 pero desde windows, luego lo he vuelto a descargar y ejecutar, he reiniciado el pc y se ha solucionado
Muchas gracias! Pablo.
